# running bash script in debug mode using java with PS4 set

Tags: java, bash, shell

i want to run my bash script in debug mode using Java  with PS4 environment variable set.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash" ,"-x", "/junk/leaptest.sh");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("PS4", "${BASH_SOURCE}:::${LINENO}:::COV:");
final Process process = pb.start();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("line no--->>" + line);
    pw.println("2000");
    pw.flush();
}
```

the output what I'm getting as it's not running in debug mode and my PS4 env is not set

The same thing work when i Use Runtime command,

```
String[] cmd = new String[3];
cmd[0] = "/bin/bash"; // should exist on all POSIX systems
cmd[1] = "-xv";
cmd[2] = args[0];

String[] env = new String[1];
env [0] = "PS4=${BASH_SOURCE}:::${LINENO}::: COV:";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println("Execing " + cmd[0]  + cmd[1]);

Process proc = rt.exec(cmd,env);
```

Comment: What's the `-x` option? I could not find it here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html

Comment: [root@ ~]# cat /junk/leaptest.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:"
read year
if (( ("$year" % 400) == "0" )) || (( ("$year" % 4 == "0") && ("$year" % 100 !=
"0") )); then
  echo "$year is a leap year."
else
  echo "This is not a leap year."
fi

[root@ ~]# leaptest.sh
Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:

[root@ ~]# bash -x /junk/leaptest.sh
echo 'Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:'
Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:
read year

Comment: set the PS4 variable to cause set -x output to include the line number:

Comment: @KARASZIIstván: Unfortunately, it's not documented there, but it is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#index-set-149) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set).

Answer (score 1):

When `bash` runs with `-x`, it writes the trace information to standard error, not standard output. You'll need to capture that with something like:

```
PrintWriter pwe = new PrintWriter(process.getErrorStream());
```